# how to convert asp.net website project to sharepoint wsp

Tags: sharepoint

I have created a Visual studio 2012 asp.net project on my local machine and now want to use in other sharepoint site.

How to convert my asp.net project to wsp file and to deploy to sharepoint environment.

Comment: I think you should read up on SharePoint development, your question is very broad. You cannot simply "convert a ASP.NET project into a WSP". You will need to create a SharePoint artefact for your ASP.NET project. Is your project a website? You could go oldschool and put it into a `_layouts` page if you want to deploy to a local server. Or you do it as you are supposed to do nowadays and create an SharePoint app for that. What version of SharePoint are you targeting? 2010? 2013? 2016?

Comment: I am using sharepoint 2013 and we don't have visual studio to create a sharepoint project in server. So I wanted to know wsp can be converted in other way with out interacting to sharepoint site.

Comment: For sharepoint development, you should ideally be running a test server with an identical sharepoint environment and Visual studio installed. Then you can easily create Sharepoint Visual Web Parts, test them, and then build into wsp files. Then you can deploy these to the production server. Doesn't answer your question I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot automatically convert asp.net project to wsp file!

You need to adjust and change your asp.net code manually so it can be deployed to SharePoint and there is a lot to consider depending on your asp.net Projects functionality and structure - wsp (full trust code with c#) vs add-in (clientside code with JavaScript and REST).

Start here at MSDN: [SharePoint general development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt674607.aspx)

If you use the new SharePoint Framework (SPFx) to develop your client-side webparts, then you don't need a Visual Studio installed on a SharePoint server. You don't even need a SharePoint server.

Using SPFx you can develop in Notepad or any other code editor.
Note that SPFx is currently (Dec 13 2016) in preview.

Start here at Office Dev Center: [Overview of SharePoint Framework (SPFx)](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)